# Change the picture from the icon tray

Tags: autohotkey

I've searched many threads about this but I couldn't understand them...

Is it possible to change the `H` icon to something else as well as `S`(suspend) which will switch to another image if it got suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Menu command. When you Suspend the program change the icon by calling the same command again with a different icon. And when unsuspending call the command again to show your regular icon.

```
; active
Menu, Tray, Icon, yourregularicon.ico ; to replace H
; suspend
Menu, Tray, Icon, yoursuspendicon.ico ; to replace H
```

Documentation: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Menu.htm

Answer (score 0):

When a script's hotkeys are suspended, its tray icon changes to the letter S. This can be avoided by freezing the icon, which is done by specifying 1 for the last parameter of the Menu command. For example:

> Menu, Tray, Icon, C:\My Icon.ico, , 1

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm#Remarks

To change the tray icon when you Suspend the script you need to define a hotkey, e.g.

```
!s::
Menu,Tray,Icon, C:\My Icon2.ico, , 1
Suspend On
return

#If (A_IsSuspended)

    !s::
    Suspend Off
    Menu,Tray,Icon, C:\My Icon.ico, , 1
    return

#If
```

or a timer:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, change_tray_icon, 100
return

    change_tray_icon:
If (A_IsSuspended)
    Menu,Tray,Icon, C:\My Icon2.ico, , 1
else
    Menu,Tray,Icon, C:\My Icon.ico, , 1
return
```